# Is the set of untrue statements recursively enumerable?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

By Tarski's Theorem, it's complement, the set of true statements in formal arithmetic, is not recursively enumerable. But the set of untrue statements might be. Is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "untrue"?  If "x is untrue" means "NOT x is true", then it is very easy to enumerate true statements given an enumerator for false statements.

Comment: I think (given the "incompleteness" tag) that the author with "untrue" does not mean "false", but "not true". E.g. "This statement is false" is not true, but also not false.

Comment: Tarski's theorem shows that the set of true statements is not arithmetically definable - which is much stronger than just not r.e.  If a set is not arithmetically definable, its complement is also not arithmetically definable.

Comment: @CarlMummert you really should give this as an answer, not as a comment :)

Comment: @Anonymous: I forgot why it was a comment, but then I remembered that this is a PSQ. It would be ideal for the OP to improve the question and to respond with the version of Tarski's theorem they are thinking of.

Comment: @Anonymous Note that such statements can't actually be expressed in the language of arithmetic. More generally, in first-order logic, if $M$ is a structure and $\varphi$ is a sentence, either $\varphi$ is true in $M$ or $\varphi$ is false in $M$; there is no middle ground.

Comment: @CarlMummert. What does PSQ stand for?

Comment: @user254665: a problem which is just a statement of a question, exactly in the form that it might be given as an assignment.

Answer (score 4):

If there were an algorithm to enumerate the false statements, just run it, and every time it produces a statement of the form "Not $S$", output $S$.  That would enumerate the true statements.